# Is it possible to capture the click event of an overlapped marker?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have a map with two types of markers. One type is the location of a store, let's call it "Store A" and the other type is "My Position". There are many "Store A" markers and one "My Position" marker. The "My Position" marker has a higher zIndex than the "Store A" markers.

My Position - Marker: zIndex = 3

Store A - Marker    : zIndex = 2

In certain cases a "Store A" marker can be slightly - let's say half - overlapped or covered by the "My Position" Marker. In this case click events do not reach the "Store A" Marker, unless I zoom in far enough, that both markers are not touching each other any more.

The "My Position" marker has no click event. It's just a visual. The "Store A" marker opens an infowindow.

Of course I can hope to use zooms in far enough but it would be more elegant to let the click event reach the marker at the back. How can this be achieved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the [clickable property](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#MarkerOptions) of the "My Position" marker to false

```
clickable | boolean | If true, the marker receives mouse and touch events. Default value is true.
```

Comment: Thank you! I missed that property.